# hibernate settimeout not working mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working in java hibernate and mysql. I want to use transaction settimeout for a payment functionality of application. I just test the code as below for settimeout to work.

```
Transaction tx = (Transaction) threadTransaction.get();
try {
    if (tx == null) {
        Session session = (Session) threadSession.get();
        session.getTransaction().setTimeout(5);
        tx=session.beginTransaction();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            System.out.println("session active");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("session inactive");
        }

        threadTransaction.set(tx);
    }
}
catch (HibernateException e) {
    throw new HibernateException("", e);
}
```

But it print session active, means the timeout doesnt work. What is the reason? please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is pretty good at doing nothing as long as nothing needs to be done (efficiency and such). I think that is what your test shows, not that the the timeout is not working for what it was [intended to do](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation-timeout):

"... ensuring that database level deadlocks and queries with huge result sets are limited by a defined timeout."
Also note that "setTimeout() cannot be called in a CMT bean ..."

Test the transaction timeout with some code that does what the transaction timeout was intended for and I think you'll find it working properly.

Comment: hai, van thanks for the reply. actually i want touse timeout long conversation, like usee choose some seats and submit. application locks those seats and commit trans. a new trans then begin for say 5mnts to let him pay amont. if he didnt pay tans fails. this is the scenario. i test it lik ths anddidnt work